# NPM: 403 forbidden - PUT http://registry.npmjs.org/[package-name] - Forbidden

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-publish

I am trying to create `npm vue component library`. I have been working through all the steps but stuck at `npm publish`.

Please see the below error screenshot for which I am unable to find a solution on google after trying more than an hour(The error message is not that accurate IMHO or maybe I am not able to catch it).

[image]

For reference `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@satyam/vue-components",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "./dist/satyam.common.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-library": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name satyam ./src/components/index.js",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

After running `npm audit`

[image]

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update: New user needs to confirm their account first**

So after quite a few research and digging around, I found the real issue here.

It's probably documented somewhere very deep or in a light font, but I totally missed to find it.

Your package name should follow your `npm username`.

In my `package.json` name property is `@satyam/vue-components` where it should be `@satyamninja/vue-components` and that's it. I successfully published the package.

Comment: For future folks. The 403 forbidden was possibly because the ORG Scope for @satyam was already taken. To make this clear, the `npm username` is not required to follow your package scope.

Answer (score 22):

If you are a new user, **please confirm your account first!**

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue straight away. So simple

Comment: I'm glad, I could help!

Comment: thanks... saved me some heartache. why doesn't npm tell you to confirm your account. the reason you are probably creating an account is to try and publish something.

Answer (score 9):

This post has helped me moving past the 403 error, however, after confirming my account over the email link they send and after login into NPM I tried one more time, then I got the following error:

402 Payment Required - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@jcarbajal79%2fsimplelib3 - You must sign up for private packages.

If you have the same problem is because the library is being published as private, I checked my package.json and test the following:

No property: "private":"...". - does not work
Property set "private":"true" - does not work
Property set "private":"false" - does not work

Turns out you have to publish it as public from the command line:

%> npm publish --access=public. - Works!.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did it for me too!

Answer (score 4):

It sound like you are a new user. You need to confirm your account. Should have get email confirmation from npm site.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error once and I figured out how to fix it after some search. you are getting the `403 forbidden error` because there is possibly another package published on NPM with the same name as the one you are trying to publish, you will have to change that to another name. to do so, you can go to your `package.json` and edit the name of the package.

Answer (score 1):

If the answers mentioned above not working for anyone then you need to check if your email is verified with the npm account or not, If it's not verified just do the verification and you will be able to publish without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens because the name you gave the component in the **name** attribute found in package.json already exists in **npm**, I recommend giving the component a different name that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and was able to resolve by logging into npmjs.com from the command line i.e.

```
npm login
Username: *******
Password:
Email: (this IS public) *******@***.***
npm notice Please check your email for a one-time password (OTP)
Enter one-time password: 49720564
Logged in as ******* on https://registry.npmjs.org/.
```

Running npm publish then succeeded and I could see my package in my account.